# ERROR /init: /init: 1 cannot open /dev/root/: No such device or address after P2V

Tags: linux, hyper-v, clonezilla

I have a problem with converting a Physical Machine to a Virtual Machine. I'm using as VM host Windows Server 2012 R2 with Hyper V. Unfortunately I'm rather the Windows Guy and can't find a solution on the Web.

We have an old server (purchase date 2007). The server has Linux installed with the Lino bootlooder.
After I cloned the server with CloneZilla, it won't boot anymore.
The error is

/init: /init: 1 cannot open /dev/root/: No such device or address
Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount …
resume: libcrypt version: 1.2.3
resume: Could not statt he resume device file
Please type in te file to try again

[IMGUR GIF -> Boot up at Hyper V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlYxv.jpg)

Unfortunately, there are still important data and management software on the server, which must be made available to the authorities for at least 3 years.  I hope you can help me.

Thx Maxis

Comment: More interesting is not just the bootloader, but other properties of that old server: Linux distro, kernel version, the hardware (in particular, was the system on the HW RAID, which one, or was it on some SATA drives, was it configured into AHCI mode or some other). Also it may help if you share the disk layout of that server and describe Hyper-V settings you used for the VM.

Comment: I mean, the error message you showed is so vague so it is hard to find out what is wrong. Also, by the way, the bootloader configuration is interesting, for instance the kernell command line.

Comment: Hi @Nikita Kipriyanov,

thanks for the quick feedback!

Unfortunately, I do not have the clue. 

Does this help you?

https://imgur.com/a/Se6sOW7